# Validate Un-compiled C# Class

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to validate that an auto-generated class I created has no syntax errors. I know how to do this in CodeDom but I am using .Net Standard 2.0 and CodeDom is not supported for what I am trying to do.

Comment: What is the context for this code generation? You are writing a tool that generates code? Are you invoking some other tool? Is it a plugin to visual studio? The standard way would be to use the roslyn compiler via Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.* packages.

Comment: You could also use [StyleCop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop)